# Horizontal scroll week calendar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, calendar

This is the thing need to develop with horizontal scroll

[image: this is the thing need to develop in my project. It should be scroll horizontal.]

Comment: In the future make your question as specific as possible including what you want to achieve, what you have tried or think is possible.

Comment: have you figured something out? i'm interested

Answer (score 0):

You can check this package  [date_picker_timeline](https://pub.dev/packages/date_picker_timeline)

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      DatePicker(
        DateTime.now(),
        initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
        selectionColor: Colors.black,
        selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
        onDateChange: (date) {
          // New date selected
          setState(() {
            _selectedValue = date;
          });
        },
      ),
    ],
)
```